# python lxml add sub_element to parent based on subelement text function vs. class

Tags: python, xml, class, lxml

Sorry this is a bit long winded but I would like to be as detailed as possible.

I have the following example xml file:

```xml
<root>
 <input_file>
   <type>x</type>
 </input_file>
 <input_file>
   <type>y</type>
 </input_file>
</root>
```

And would like to add subelements based on the `<type>` tag using the python lxml package in python3.9 so that the xml file looks like this:

```xml
<root>
 <input_file>
   <type>x</type>
   <path>hi</path>
 </input_file>
 <input_file>
   <type>y</type>
   <path>hi_again</path>
 </input_file>
</root>
```

The below code works:

```py
from lxml import etree as LET

xml_file = 'test.xml'
tree = LET.parse(xml_file)
root = tree.getroot()

for input_file in root.findall('input_file'):

    type_element = input_file.find('type')

    if type_element.text == 'x':

        c = LET.SubElement(input_file, 'path')
        c.text = 'hi'

    elif type_element.text == 'y':

        c = LET.SubElement(input_file, 'path')
        c.text = 'hi_again'

LET.indent(root, space="  ")
tree.write(xml_file)
```

When I try to do this from the following class I created (file XMLReader.py):

```py
from lxml import etree as LET
import string

class XMLReader(object):

    def __init__(self, file_path):

        self.file_path = file_path
        self.tree = LET.parse(self.file_path)
        self.root = self.tree.getroot()

    def set_sub_element(self, parent_tag, tag, info):

        child = LET.SubElement(parent_tag, tag)
        child.text = self.clean_string(info)
        self.root.append(child)
        LET.indent(self.root, space="  ")
        self.tree.write(self.file_path)

    def get_all_elements(self, tag):

        try:
            return self.root.findall(tag)

        except AttributeError:

            return None

    def clean_string(self, s):

        return ''.join(filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, s))
```

with the following code:

```py
from XMLReader import XMLReader

items = {'x':'hi', 'y': 'hi_again'}
xml_file = 'test.xml'
xml_test = XMLReader(xml_file)
input_file_tags = xml_test.get_all_elements('input_file')

for input_file in input_file_tags:

    type_element = input_file.find('type')

    if type_element.text in items:

        item = items[type_element.text]

        xml_test.set_sub_element(input_file, 'path', item)
```

I get the following resulting file:

```xml
<root>
  <input_file>
    <type>x</type>
  </input_file>
  <input_file>
    <type>y</type>
  </input_file>
  <path>hi</path>
  <path>hi_again</path>
</root>
```

I am wondering what I am doing wrong here to obtain the same result as above where the resulting `<path></path>` is not a subelement of `<input_file></input_file>` based on the `<type></type>` value.

Comment: TBH your working code looks like a perfectly good solution; why are you motivated to rewrite it in a more complicated and ultimately unsuccessful way?

Comment: @balmy Because I would like to use it with multiple scripts and not want to repeat myself every time.

Comment: You could do that by wrapping your working code in a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as an exericse, here's a relatively simple way of doing it:

```
#start with your `items`
items = {'x':'hi', 'y': 'hi_again'}
tags = ['input_file','type']
for v in items.keys():
    destination = root.xpath(f'//{tags[0]}/{tags[1]}[text()="{v}"]/..')[0]
    new_elem=LET.fromstring(f'<path>{items[v]}</path>')
    destination.insert(1,new_elem)
LET.indent(root, space="  ")
print(LET.tostring(root).decode())
```

Output:

```
<root>
  <input_file>
    <type>x</type>
    <path>hi</path>
  </input_file>
  <input_file>
    <type>y</type>
    <path>hi_again</path>
  </input_file>
</root>
```

Comment: this works in my class.  Appreciate the help!

Comment: follow-up question.  Let me know if I should open another question.  Once created, I am trying to modify the text in the newly created ```<path>```.  I have tried modifying the command:

```destination.insert(1, new_elem)```

to:

```destination.replace('path', new_elem)```

with no success.  Is there something I am not understanding?

Thanks.

Comment: @PhilL Yes, don't try to do it with a comment. A new question is preferable.

Comment: Ok.  Done.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question what you did wrong in your code:
In the `set_sub_element` method, you are first adding the new child as subelement to the designated parent (in your code `<input_file/>`). The [`SubElement` factory](https://lxml.de/apidoc/lxml.etree.html#lxml.etree.SubElement) from `lxml.etree` creates a new element and appends it to the parent. This should be enough to produce your output.

However, in the same method you then append the new child to the root. This moves the element to a different position in the tree (i.e. it is now a child of the root instead of `<input_file/>`). So you should remove the line where the child is appended to the root. The `set_sub_element` method would then just be like this:

```
def set_sub_element(self, parent_tag, tag, info):
   child  = LET.SubElement(parent_tag, tag)
   child.text = self.clean_string(info)
   LET.indent(self.root, space=" ")
   self.tree.write(self.file_path)
```